# Jest 14 -> 15 upgrade: Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function but got: undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs

After upgrading my react-native 0.30 app from Jest 14.1.0 to 15.1.0, I started getting the following error in most (but not all) of my tests:

```
Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.                                                                                                                

  at invariant (node_modules/fbjs/lib/invariant.js:38:15)                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  at instantiateReactComponent [as _instantiateReactComponent] (node_modules/react/lib/instantiateReactComponent.js:86:134)                                                                                                                                                 
  at ReactCompositeComponentMixin.performInitialMount (node_modules/react/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:358:22)                                                                                                                                                            
  at ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent (node_modules/react/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:241:21)                                                                                                                                                                 
  at Object.ReactReconciler.mountComponent (node_modules/react/lib/ReactReconciler.js:49:35)                                                                                                                                                                                
  at ReactCompositeComponentMixin.performInitialMount (node_modules/react/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:367:34)                                                                                                                                                            
  at ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent (node_modules/react/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:241:21)                                                                                                                                                                 
  at Object.ReactReconciler.mountComponent (node_modules/react/lib/ReactReconciler.js:49:35)                                                                                                                                                                                
  at ReactCompositeComponentMixin.performInitialMount (node_modules/react/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:367:34)                                                                                                                                                            
  at ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent (node_modules/react/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js:241:21)                                                                                                                                                                 
  at Object.ReactReconciler.mountComponent (node_modules/react/lib/ReactReconciler.js:49:35)                                                                                                                                                                                
  at mountComponentIntoNode (node_modules/react/lib/ReactTestMount.js:47:31)                                                                                                                                                                                                
  at ReactTestReconcileTransaction.Mixin.perform (node_modules/react/lib/Transaction.js:138:20)                                                                                                                                                                             
  at batchedMountComponentIntoNode (node_modules/react/lib/ReactTestMount.js:61:27)                                                                                                                                                                                         
  at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.Mixin.perform (node_modules/react/lib/Transaction.js:138:20)                                                                                                                                                                   
  at Object.ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.batchedUpdates (node_modules/react/lib/ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:63:19)
```

These are all tests using `react-test-renderer` and generally look like the following:

```
import 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import Foo from '../Foo'

// Note: test renderer must be required after react-native.
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'

describe('<Foo />', () => {
  it('renders correctly', () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(
      <Foo loading={false} dispatch={() => {}} />
    ).toJSON()
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
  })
})
```

This exact same test file works for one of my components, but fails if I try most of my other components.  All of these tests work properly under Jest 14.1.0.

The error message is not very descriptive. Do you know what might be going on?

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be our use of `babel-plugin-rewire`.  The solution was to ensure that we only enabled rewire for mocha and not for jest.

In our .babelrc, we changed `test` to `mochatest`:

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native"],
  "env": {
    "mochatest": {
      "plugins": ["babel-plugin-rewire"]
    }
  }
}
```

In our test runner, we make sure to set BABEL_ENV to mochatest only before we invoke mocha and not jest.

```
export BABEL_ENV="mochatest" && mocha && export BABEL_ENV="jesttest" && jest
```